# Query Selecting Row when using distinct

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I would like to do the following.

Lets say the data looks somthing like this

```
Number  letter  
1        b      
1        c      
1        a       
2        d       
2        b        
2        c
3        a
3        b
3        c
```

I want to filter the data in the folowing way column number  to get all the distinct numbers and then also filter out the letter d

The output should be as follows

```
Number letter 
1     
2 
2       d
3
```

Would this be possible?

I can do this in two table but i would like to know if it was possible to combine  it into one

thank you

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select distinct number, case when letter = 'd' then 'd' end letter from mytable
```

In Oracle you can use `decode` to shorten the query:

```
select distinct number, decode(letter, 'd', 'd') letter from mytable
```

Comment: I have not tried the first one yet, but the second one works excellent THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

How about `union all`?

```
select distinct number, null as letter
from t
union all
select number, 'd'
from t
where letter = 'd';
```

Comment: I will look in to this syntax, I am a beginner at this so every is useful thanks